# When rendering modal/component i want background to have a dark color

Tags: css, reactjs

Hello so i use a portal Component that looks like this that is used to create "modals"

```
export const ModalWindow = (props: RenderableProps<Props>) => {

  if (!props.display) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Portal parentNode={props.parentNode} renderOnMount={true}>
      <div id='modal' className={props.largeModal ? 'modal-large' : 'modal-small'}>
       {props.children}
      </div>
    </Portal>
  )
}
```

Then i have this component that i then render inside that modal

```
 export const ShowInformation = (props: RenderableProps<Props>) => {
  return (
    <div className='blur-out-menu'>
      <div className='information-content'>
        <span className='information-title'>Show Information?</span>
        <span className='information-text'>Click check button to show information</span>
        <div className='button-section'>
          <div className='decline-button' onClick={() => props.onShow(false)}>
            <CancelButton />
          </div>
          <div className='check-button' onClick={() => props.onShow(true)}>
            <CheckButton />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

what is important here is the `blur-out-menu` that i just want to use to blur out everything except the modal but i cant figure it out either it just covers the same area as the modal or if i put position fixed it messes it up totally and nothing inside the modal keeps in place. is there any nice way of doing this?

here is the css for the `blur-out-menu`

```
.blur-out-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

the modal got z-index 5 so it is above this blur out

here is the modal css as well

```
 .modal-small {
  background-color: #1E2933;
  top: 25%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: You may render your overlay as a sibling `<div>`. Nesting one into another causes the issues you're having. You may refer to one of my recent [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60193680/11299053) for a complete demo of that approach (if you find it helpful, upvotes are greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov oh nice thank you will check it out

Answer (score 0):

In `.blur-out-menu` change `height` property to `100vh` and `width` property to `100vw`
This should to the trick.

Comment: this messes with all the children below the blur-out-menu thou.. hmm i might need to put this blur out on another component

Comment: `.blur-out-menu` should be a children of `body`. then it will work just like you want it to.